# Please give global chat edit permissions to the robot

Tags: feature-request, chat

Little spelling mistakes happen all too frequently. Instead of having him point out our mistakes and hope that we are quick enough to edit them in time he should be able to do the job himself.

Comment: robot = http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/46642, and the robot suggested this at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2891070#2891070

Comment: Sounds like a slippery slope to me. Today you give him edit permissions, tomorrow he'll be controlling our nukes.

Comment: The real question becomes... who programmed the Robot?

Comment: I see that it's Friday.

Comment: I get that this is clever and all, but it's unclear what you're *really* suggesting. Do you want to give *all* users editing privileges for other people's comments? Or do you want to give *only* R. Martinho Fernandes those rights? Or...something else?

Comment: @rubenvb I already believe that all SO moderators are just Jon Skeet's programming done in his free time.